# Implement Method Gauss Jordan Elimination in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, stringgrid

This is my homework from my school to make Gauss-jordan elimination in delphi, but..I got some problem here...

I Made like this :

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  n,i,j,k,bar,kol:integer;
  a:array [1..100,1..100]of real;
  x:array [1..100]of real;
  faktor:real;
begin
  memo1.Clear;
  n:=stringgrid2.RowCount-1;
  kenalmatriks;
  StringGrid2.RowCount := baris;
  StringGrid2.ColCount := kolom;

  for i:=1 to n do
  begin
    for j:=1 to n+1 do
    begin
      a[i,j]:=strtofloat(stringgrid1.cells[j,i]);
    end;
  end;

  for k:=1 to n do
  begin
    faktor:=a[k,k];
    for j:=1 to n+1 do
    begin
      a[j,k]:=a[j,k]/faktor;
    end;
    for i:=1 to n do
    begin
      if i<>k then
      begin
        faktor:=a[i,k];
        for j:=1 to n+1 do
        begin
          a[i,j]:=a[i,j]-faktor*a[k,j];
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  for bar:=1 to n do
  begin
    for kol:=1 to n+1 do
    begin
      stringgrid2.cells[kol,bar]:=floattostr(a[bar,kol]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The result must like this :

```
1   0   0   2
0   1   0   7
0   0   1   -3
```

But, mine :

```
--   --   --   --
--   1    0    15.33
--   0    1    2
```

I hope I can finish this... :(
anyone...please help...

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: why are you using `strtofloat` if you want whole numbers?

Comment: We now know the expected output but have no clue what the input values are.  Please make an effort and show a complete example.

Comment: Seems you have more than one problem here, your array starts at 1,1 but you access values from a stringgrid which would start at 0,0 (stringgrid1.cells[0,0] would be the top left value). As long as we dont know what your stringgrid looks like I would say you miss some values.

Comment: You must do what I have told you at least once already. Make an SSCCE. A complete program. That contains the input hard coded. With no GUI. A console app that prints output to console. That we can paste into our compiler. Gauss-Jordan is simple enough. Once you supply SSCCE we'll be able to correct. Remember to keep the numerical code separate from the output. Don't mix maths and GUI. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I don't know anything about Gauss-jordan elimination and never heard of it.

The answer is clear though!

Either your math is off, or you are grabbing the wrong numbers.

As was suggested by manuell in the first comment to your post, you need to see what numbers are being used.

A simple way to debug in console that I use is: `writeln('whatever variable: ' + VARIABLE)`.

you can use a `MemoList` if you are in a GUI development to do the same thing. You will be surprised of the results sometimes.

Also use the right functions for what you want `floatToStr` and `strToFloat` are not what you want probably.

**Edit:**

Looked up Gauss-jordan elimination also known as row reduction and it turns out to be simple matrices algebra.

I never knew that is what is called likely because although attributed to Gauss, it was [already known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#History) to Chinese mathematicians in 179 AD.

A good example is found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xc37YM59vVA

A good example in Delphi, although written in an earlier version: Delphi-3 programming language, with source code is found [here](http://www.davdata.nl/math/gauss.html)

Another example but has much more than Gaussian elimination so you have to look at the code can be found [here](http://www.monash.edu.au/policy/spartext.htm)

[Here](http://megasnippets.com/en/source-codes/cpp/gauss_jordan_elimination) is an example in C++

So now I am sure you have solved it or lost your login to SO. Good luck and enjoy the process as that is the best part.